# PWA update icon after user add to homescreen

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I want to change my app icon. I've tried changed it but the app icon (already add to homescreen or installed on app drawer) not change.

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
        "src": "react.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

I've changed the name and icons on size 144x144 but nothing happened.

Can I change the app icon after user add to home screen?

I've read `Tip: Icons may be cached, so it may be helpful to change the filenames when updating icons or other graphics.`
but wait for 24 hours, the icon never change until now.

Comment: Are you trying to change the already added icon in the homescreen? Why not try to uninstall that and re-Add-to-Homescreen the updated app and see if your new icon takes effect?

Comment: @noogui i know the icon already takes effect. what i want in the future if user already add to their homescreen and I change the icon.

Comment: I believe currently once it is installed you are done. It does NOT look to the manifest to see if it should be updated. So, pick an Icon you like before you go live.

Comment: Did you find out how to update the icon? I don't understand why this question got an down vote :( I voted it up since this is something we want to know. I hope Google updates the documentation how to update the icon more clearly.

Answer (score 7):

PWA icons are only updated when the instal method is a [WebAPK](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks). If it is an older version of of PWA, on an unsupported platform, or does not meet the [criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria) for WebAPK then it will just an [Android OS bookmark](https://medium.com/@firt/android-oreo-takes-a-bite-out-of-progressive-web-apps-30b7e854648f#a5fb). Browser doesn't know when to update the icon on OS bookmarks.

Check the list of installed apps in Android's settings (not the drawer) and if your PWA isn't listed there it can't update the image.

Answer (score 2):

Force iOS to reload the image by adding `?=...` to the end of its name in your HTML. The image name itself doesn't require updating.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="600x600" href="images/app-icon-600.png?=v2" />
```

1. Remove your PWA from your homescreen.
2. Delete your Safari's cached data for your website (Settings > Safari > Advanced > Website Data).
3. Reinstall your PWA.

Answer (score 1):

## 19th Dec 2022

> Changes to `name`, `short_name` and `icons` are not currently supported on desktop Chrome, though work is underway to support them.

> Changes to `name`, `short_name` and `icons` are not currently supported on Android Chrome, though work is underway to support them.

https://web.dev/manifest-updates/

Comment: Regarding “Work is underway to support them” the whole page was last updated 2021-10-26, which can mean it’s soon fixed or long time forgotten.