# PWA: Chrome for Android is caching the icon too aggressively

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon, progressive-web-apps

I have a working PWA. Lighthouse shows that the PWA should be OK to be installed, and the install prompt is showing in Chrome for Android. The Chrome DevTools on PC show the new icon.

I recently changed my app's icon to a new one that was provided by our marketing department. However, **the install prompt is still showing the old icon**. All favicons show the new one and on Safari the new icon is displayed, too.

Here's what I've tried:

- Added `?v=123` to the end of the icon path
- Cleared the browser storage in chrome
- Restarted the phone
- Ensured that all new images were available in the same resolution as the old images

The footer of this sample image shows which prompt I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52156729/5832311), PWA icons are only updated when the install method is a [WebAPK](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks). If it is an older version of PWA on an unsupported platform, or does not meet the [criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria) for WebAPK then it will just an Android OS bookmark. You may check the list of installed apps in Android's settings (not the drawer) and if your PWA isn't listed there, it can't update the image.

Comment: AFAIK if the criteria aren't all fulfilled, the prompt won't show. In my case, the prompt is shown, and the app can be installed. It shows up in my app list, with the old icon, even if reinstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old question but I got stuck on something like this since yesterday. What I describe is a sequence that I followed and worked in my case.

If it is an App, installed by Chrome on Android using PWA, try to:

1. Force stop
2. Clear cache
3. Clear data
4. Uninstall
5. Reinstall

Worked for me. I understand that the question was about browser context, but I hope this can help someone.